# Transform replaced strings in array

Tags: php, arrays, regex

I have the following code:

```
<?php
$text = 'Hey @Mathew, have u talked with @Jhon today?';
    $text = preg_replace('/(^|\s)@([A-Za-z0-9]*)/', '\1<a href="profile.php?user=\\2">@\\2</a>',$text);
?>
```

And my goal is notify the user was quoted.
To do that, I thought: I put all the replaced strings in a array and pick only the name; using the example above, and following the thinking, I have this result:

```
['Mathew', 'Jhon']
```

So, how can I have the last result?

Comment: How does that PHP give you `{'Mathew', 'Jhon'}`?

Comment: It's an example of array...

Comment: `preg_replace` doesn't give back an array though..or not when passed a string.

Comment: See [this PHP demo](http://rextester.com/WWN90585).

Comment: "***It's an example of array...***" I'm not aware of any programing language which arrays are declared with curly brackets `{}`, objects normally are.  Did you mean brackets `[]` ?

Comment: *I have this result* end of discussion.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It's what I needed. Thank's.

Comment: Not an answer, but your pattern can be improved writing `@(?<!\S.)` in place of `(^|\s)@`

Comment: I wanted to add that (similar) enhancement, but it makes little sense in this scenario, the gain will be  too small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may actually collect matches while performing a regex-based search and replace if you use `preg_replace_callback`:

```
$text = 'Hey @Mathew, have u talked with @Jhon today?';
$names = [];
$text = preg_replace_callback('/(^|\s)@([A-Za-z0-9]*)/', function($m) use (&$names) {
        $names[] = $m[2];
        return $m[1] . '<a href="profile.php?user=' . $m[2] . '">@' . $m[2] . '</a>';
    },$text);
echo "$text\n";
print_r($names);
```

See the [PHP demo](http://rextester.com/WWN90585)

Output:

```
Hey <a href="profile.php?user=Mathew">@Mathew</a>, have u talked with <a href="profile.php?user=Jhon">@Jhon</a> today?
Array
(
    [0] => Mathew
    [1] => Jhon
)
```

Note the array variable for the matches is passed to the anonymous function with the `use (&$names)` syntax. The `$m` is a match object containing the whole match in the first item and captures in the subsequent items.

Answer (score 1):

Before replacing the text you can use `preg_match` to find all users in the string:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Example:

```
$text = 'Hey @Mathew, have u talked with @Jhon today?';

preg_match($pattern, $text, $matches);
var_dump($matches);

$text = preg_replace('/(^|\s)@([A-Za-z0-9]*)/', '\1<a href="profile.php?user=\\2">@\\2</a>',$text);
```

You will have to alter your pattern for this to work.

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: pattern

Comment: You'll need to define the pattern yourself, I didn't include it since yours gives back a space in the matches array the preg_match gives back. Please try reading the documentation I linked instead of just copying and pasting the code

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use a regex like `/@[a-z0-9]+/sim`, i.e.:

```
$text = 'Hey @Mathw, have u talked with @Jhon today?';
preg_match_all('/@[a-z0-9]+/sim', $text , $handles_array, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$text = preg_replace('/(@[a-z0-9]+)/sim', '<a href="profile.php?user=$1">$1</a>', $text);
print($text);
print_r($handles_array[0]);
```

---

**Output:**

```
Hey <a href="profile.php?user=@Mathw">@Mathw</a>, have u talked with <a href="profile.php?user=@Jhon">@Jhon</a> today?Array
(
    [0] => @Mathw
    [1] => @Jhon
)
```

---

Live Demo:

https://ideone.com/oU6xbb

---

Note:

> "It's an example of array..."

I'm not aware of any programing language which arrays are declared with curly brackets `{}`, objects normally are.  Did you mean brackets `[]`?

Comment: It seems that OP needs an array of names after replacement.